# How to prevent a mutiny by the senior employees whom I manage?

Tags: management, motivation, people-management

What are the courses of action I can take as a manager if the senior employees of my team keep complaining and resisting me?

I believe the main reasons for their behavior are:
1. I was promoted early in my career into management, some of them have more technical experience in the field. I was promoted for always delivering exactly what senior management wanted. I often perceive multiple symptoms of jealousy by the "team lead".
2. There was a lot of change across the company and especially my department: computers taking over job, instructions from above, etc.

My ideal situation is that I deliver good results, and that should also include preventing a mutiny I guess.

Comment: *Sidenote off-question: I am really fed up with my questions being voted down because they are "not clear". I see absolutely no reason why they aren't. Now this is the most concise version of it. So please if you don't see what's clear about this question, at least tell me how to make it more clear!*

Comment: If multiple senior members are complaining and resisting have you considered that it might be something you are doing? Have you tried talking to them to see how you can improve the working relationship?

Comment: Also Just as a side note if you register an account you will be able to keep access to all of your questions, answers and comments and be able to edit and vote ect. At the moment you are creating a new account each time. Registering makes things like this much easier! Thanks in advance and welcome :)

Comment: I agree with RhysW. Perhaps try more to listen to, understand, and address what you call their "complaints" instead of merely ascribing these complaints to jealously and resistance to change. "Delivering results" in the short term sounds nice but if you lose your team in the process, that will eventually destroy your reputation as a "results-driven" manager.

Comment: Your sidenote comment makes me wonder if you act towards your employees the same as you act here, considering your perspective to be the only valid one. Just because something is clear to you doesn't mean it is clear to anyone else, and presenting aggressively that it is will tend to create friction. You would be much better off saying that you are open to questions that would help you make the question clearer, and/or that you have tried your best and hope that it is sufficiently clear.

Comment: @NewBoss, I edited your previous question (http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18531/how-to-respond-when-my-senior-staff-is-constantly-negative-towards-me). I think it includes more relevant information than this one. Please follow up on that one in case it gets reopened or is answered.

Comment: Can we come to a consensus on which question of @NewBoss we need to look into? Multiple people are editing older questions while the questions are being asked again and again in different formats!

Comment: Agree with @Unsung -- I'd suggest closing/merging the questions.

I'd suggest this one - it's the newest *I think* and least verbose.

Comment: ^ I'd suggest *keeping* this one

Comment: I'm going to write the same thing I wrote on a previous question. You obviously have multiple serious problems here, which in my opinion are beyond the ability of a website to address. You should talk to someone in person. I recommend talking both to your boss, and to someone who has been in the industry and has more experience than yourself, but isn't involved in the situation.

Comment: Downvote for irrelevantly discussing downvotes in comment section

Comment: Is there a suitable in location you could get a plank installed? Then mutinous employees could walk it. Worked for Captain Cook.

Comment: Cook was a great captin and navigator, and I'm pretty sure he never made anyone walk the plank. (He said, downvoting himself for being offtopic).

Comment: @NewBoss Your situation is [being discussed in meta.](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/one-user-seem-to-be-posting-from-at-least-four-accounts-please-help-to-sort-i) Can you please register properly and use just the one account?

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, I would suggest that if this one person that you're having a problem with then it might be either one of you that's the root cause of the problem or it might be a simple personality clash. If it's several people (as implied by 'employees') then this suggests that the problem is with you, I'm afraid.

> What are the courses of action I can take as a manager if the senior employees of my team keep complaining and resisting me?
>   ...
>   I believe the main reasons for their behavior are

You might start by stopping making assumptions ("I believe the main reasons...") and *asking* them what their reasons are when they disagree with you.

What do you define as "mutiny" anyway? If they're disagreeing with you over an important issue then provided they have the best interests of the company and/or department at heart, this can hardly be described as mutiny. Given that most people find conflict to be hard work, I would suggest that you should be most worried if they're instead utterly indifferent to what you say and do.

You need to speak to your team and listen to their responses. You need to build mutual trust with them. You won't do either of those things by dismissing their disagreements with you as jealousy, or by taking the same attitude with them that you've shown here with your 'sidenote' comment.

Comment: For managers, "mutiny" is usually a word used to describe when people they manage do not agree with them. I have worked for managers in the past who already have made their mind up how something will/should be done. When far more competent technical people disagreed with the manager (with many valid reasons), the manager would turn it into a discussion about "why are you resisting me? let's try and solve YOUR problem so that we can go forward together and implement MY ideas". In their mind, the group was being mutinious.

Comment: agreed @mike - I was trying to pin down if that was the case here.